# Can I use RequestHeader annotation in spring servlet filter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Can I use RequestHeader annotation in spring servlet filter like OncePerRequestFilter? Will Spring inject the header value into the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the purpose of what you want to do, but in OncePerRequestFilter you can do

```
httpServletRequest.getHeader("header");
```

Comment: I understood. Basically it's a wrong question. You can't change the signature of the methods already there unlike controller class. Still accepting the answer, thanks.